# Django error while running server settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, import, settings

I'm trying to execute

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But it throws an error saying

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'survivalguide.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named survivalguide.settings
```

I installed Anaconda with python 2.7 and set up a virtualenv.

**My manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "survivalguide.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**My current os.path**

```
[
    '',
    '/Users/KWYI/Documents/Python_Practice/Django_Practice/survivalguide',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python27.zip',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/Users/KWYI/anaconda/envs/PyCon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg'
]
```

I'm troubleshooting for hours now and still can't figure out what the problem is.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show the layout of your `Django_Practice` directory.

Comment: @Alasdair it looks like Django_Practice/survivalguide/ and within the survivalguide there are a few files such as __init__.py
__init__.pyc
db.sqlite3
manage.py
settings.py
settings.pyc
templates
urls.py
views.py
wsgi.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `'survivalguide.settings'` usually works because `manage.py` is in the directory above `settings.py`.

You have `manage.py` in the same directory as `settings.py`, which is unusual. I would recommend moving `manage.py` into the parent directory. I would avoid using a custom project layout unless you understand what you are doing, otherwise you might hit more issues like this.

If you can't do that, you could either change the line to:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
```

or you could manually add `/Users/KWYI/Documents/Python_Practice/Django_Practice/` to the python path.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I tried moving `manage.py` into the parent directory and ran `python manage.py runserver` and it now says it cannot find the `manage.py`. So i tried your next advice and a new error pops up `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'survivalguide.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module survivalguide.wsgi: "No module named survivalguide.wsgi"
`

Comment: If you move `manage.py` into the parent directory, then you need to change to the parent directory before you run `python manage.py`. The *No module named `survivalguide.wsgi`* error is the same issue as you have in `manage.py` - either the parent directory has to be on the python path, or you have to change the `survivalguide.wsgi` to `wsgi`.